# Animate object with speed of Scroll with finger in Android

Tags: android, animation, scrollview, android-animation

I am trying to create an animation with `ImageView` objects, where the objects change their position with respect to the touch motion.

Eg: Refer this behance link : https://www.behance.net/gallery/32233691/ELEVATE-Onboarding

I can create translation animations however they have a timing set which must be changed by me.

1. How do I set this timing in respect to touch motion.

Things I have tried:
1. I am trying Android ViewPager with a shared Transition Element.
The code is available on this url : https://medium.com/@BashaChris/the-android-viewpager-has-become-a-fairly-popular-component-among-android-apps-its-simple-6bca403b16d4

Comment: Can anybody comment why they gave me a -1.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by importing following package

```
import com.github.florent37.viewanimator.ViewAnimator;
```

Then add following code.

```
ViewAnimator
             .animate(YourImageView,text)
             .rotation(360)
             .scale(0,1)
             .start();
```

You can use the your custom animation

Comment: I have tried it but, the animation but it is not in sync with the speed of finger scroll.